# Selenium Webdriver | Exception while read username and password for gmail from excelsheet

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, file-io, nullpointerexception, fileinputstream

Below is the exception I'm getting while trying to read username and password of gmail from the Excel file stored on the specific location, tried with adding excel in the project as well. Please help in resolving this issue.

[Exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bLd7k.png)

```
  log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ThreadSafeClientConnManager).
    log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
    log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
    Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\selenuim (Access is denied)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at SeleniumPackage.ExcelUtils.setExcelFile(ExcelUtils.java:45)
        at SeleniumPackage.ExcelUtils.main(ExcelUtils.java:36)
```

This is the code for reading username and password to login into gmail.

```
public class ExcelUtils {

    public static final String Path_TestData = "D:\\selenuim\\";
    public static final String File_TestData = "TestData.xls";
    public static HSSFSheet ExcelWSheet;
    public static HSSFWorkbook ExcelWBook;
    public static HSSFCell Cell;
    public static HSSFRow Row;  
    public static WebDriver  driver;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception     {
                File pathToBinary = new File("C:\\Users\\sajjankumar.parjapat\\AppData\\Local\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe");      
        FirefoxBinary ffBinary = new FirefoxBinary(pathToBinary);
        FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(ffBinary,profile);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        setExcelFile(Path_TestData,File_TestData);
        Login();
    }

    public static void setExcelFile(String path, String SheetName) throws Exception     {
        try         {
            FileInputStream ExcelFile = new FileInputStream(path);
            ExcelWBook = new HSSFWorkbook(ExcelFile);
            ExcelWSheet = ExcelWBook.getSheet(SheetName);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            throw (e);          }
    }

    public static String getCellData(int RowNum, int ColNum)        {
        try         {
            Cell = ExcelWSheet.getRow(RowNum).getCell(ColNum);
            String CellData = Cell.getStringCellValue();
            System.out.println(CellData);
            return CellData ; 
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            throw (e);          }
    }

    public static void Login() throws InterruptedException      {
        String url = "https://www.google.com";
        driver.get(url);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='gbw']/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/a")).click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        String Username = getCellData(1,1) ;
        String pwd = getCellData(1,2);
        driver.findElement(By.id("Email")).sendKeys(Username);
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        driver.findElement(By.id("next")).click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        driver.findElement(By.id("Passwd")).sendKeys(pwd);
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        driver.findElement(By.id("signIn")).click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);

        try         {
            Boolean oldVersion = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='browsers']/h2")).isDisplayed();
                    if(oldVersion)                      {
                        Thread.sleep(2000);
                        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='browsers']/p/b[2]/a")).click();
                    }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;            }
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        WebElement signOut = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='gb_71']"));
        signOut.click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. don't automate gmail, it's against google's TOS.  2. don't use excel spreadsheet as a data source, it's a horrible idea. 3. don't use overly complex xpath locators, they are brittle. 4. don't add unnecessary sleeps, use explicit waits instead

Comment: Thanks Corey, will take care in future however i'm new in selenium and in learning phase. Will learn thing with the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give full path to the file as a parameter to the

```
new FileInputStream(path)
```

constructor, but you are giving only folder path (public static final String Path_TestData = "D:\selenuim\";)

So change the line

```
FileInputStream ExcelFile = new FileInputStream(path);
```

to

```
FileInputStream ExcelFile = new FileInputStream(path+SheetName);
```

in the method setExcelFile

Comment: As suggested, Aftet updated with FileInputStream ExcelFile = new FileInputStream(path+SheetName); this exception resolved how ever getting another exception. while calling Login() method

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at SeleniumPackage.ExcelUtils.Login(ExcelUtils.java:71)
 at SeleniumPackage.ExcelUtils.main(ExcelUtils.java:37)

Comment: I'm not surprised. Your code is trying to open sheet by filename in line 25 { ExcelWSheet = ExcelWBook.getSheet(SheetName); } You are sending variable File_TestData which is filename as an argument SheetName to the method setExcelFile. (I believe that sheetname in your excel file is not the same as your filename). Sheetname is what you can see in the bottom of the excel page. (By default it is "Sheet1") for a just created excel document. Manage this and it should be fine

Comment: After adding this this worked. ExcelWSheet = ExcelWBook.getSheet(ExcelWBook.getSheetName(0));

Comment: I'm using XSSFWorkbook instead of HSSFWorkbook, so not sure if next will work for you, but you can try: ExcelWSheet = ExcelWBook.getSheetAt(0)